# How to extract top-K layer in the of VGG16 in Keras R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to extract the features from the predicted image.
It is based on this [article](https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.nb.html) by JJ. Allaire.

Basically what it does is to used trained model and select
top-K layers and identify region of the images that is activated in
each layer.

My model can be downloaded **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1eprp9taaclyao/model.hdf5?dl=0)** (134Mb), and the test cat image can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bmt1rvt6vuwsmj/cat.5009.jpg?dl=0).

The model looks like this:

```
> summary(model)
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                                                           Output Shape                                                                  Param #                       
===================================================================================================================================================================================================
vgg16 (Model)                                                                          (None, 4, 4, 512)                                                             14714688                      
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)                                                                    (None, 8192)                                                                  0                             
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                                                                        (None, 256)                                                                   2097408                       
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                                                                        (None, 1)                                                                     257                           
===================================================================================================================================================================================================
Total params: 16,812,353
Trainable params: 16,552,193
Non-trainable params: 260,160
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

This is my complete code:

```
library(keras)
model_file <- "data/kaggle_cats_dogs_small/model//model.hdf5"
model <- load_model_hdf5(model_file)
summary(model)

img_path <- "data/kaggle_cats_dogs_small/test_generic/cat.5009.jpg"
# We preprocess the image into a 4D tensor
img <- image_load(img_path, target_size = c(150, 150))
img_tensor <- image_to_array(img)
img_tensor <- array_reshape(img_tensor, c(1, 150, 150, 3))
# Remember that the model was trained on inputs
# that were preprocessed in the following way:
img_tensor <- img_tensor / 255
dim(img_tensor)


# Display picture ---------------------------------------------------------

plot(as.raster(img_tensor[1,,,]))

# Extracting layers and activation ----------------------------------------
# Extracts the outputs of the top 8 layers:
layer_outputs <- lapply(model$layers[1:8], function(layer) layer$output)
# Creates a model that will return these outputs, given the model input:
activation_model <- keras_model(inputs = model$input, outputs = layer_outputs)
```

It breaks at the last two lines of codes:

```
> layer_outputs <- lapply(model$layers[1:8], function(layer) layer$output)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: Layer vgg16 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead. > # Creates a model that will return these outputs, given the model input:
> activation_model <- keras_model(inputs = model$input, outputs = layer_outputs)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1_4:0", shape=(?, 150, 150, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

When this message (multiple inbound nodes) appears, it means that the model was used with another input other than its original input. (Thus the model has many inputs, although you're using only one of the possible pathes. Namely, it has the VGG original input and also another input that you used to create the stacked model).

To do what you want to do, you must do it before creating your stacked model.

Some pseudocode (sorry for not being acquainted with R notation):

```
VGGModel <- functionToCreateVGG
layer_outputs <- lapply(VGGModel$layers[1:8], function(layer) layer$output)
activation_model <- keras_model(inputs = VGGModel$input, outputs = layer_outputs)
```

When you do this before adding your top layers, the VGG model doesn't have multiple inbound nodes yet.

Now you stack your top layers onto the VGG model as you did before.

Another option is simply create another VGG model just for the `activation_model` (in case you didn't train the VGG model).

Comment: thanks. What's python way for `functionToCreateVGG` ?

Comment: `keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=someShape, pooling=None, classes=None)`  -- Assuming that you are only using the convolutional part of the model and that you don't want any global pooling at the end.